# Storing data in a service vs externally in Angular

Tags: angularjs, performance

I have a long list of countries wrapped in a constant service in Angular. For lookup, I was concerned about whether or not the entire list of countries is loaded when injected into the controller. If the entire list is loaded at run time I was wondering if, for performance's sake, I would be better off loading the data externally and accessing only the country I want via some API.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd consider:

1) Including it in the initial application load will be the fastest at runtime.

2) How often will the country list get used? If it is not used often, load it on demand from an API when it's needed.

3) After minification and compression, what is the difference in file size for your application? If the difference is small, whatever that means to you, then loading the country list when your application loads is not a big deal.